# Cannot read property 'number1' of null javascript mongodb error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I get all the data from my database in my console, but when these data has finished it always give me the following error Cannot read property 'number1' of null i tried try catch if else everything but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated

```
col1.find({},function(err, companies) {

    companies.each(function(err,company){
            console.log (company.number1);
        });
});

});
```

Comment: It simply means that the value of the variable "company" is `null`.

Comment: oh thank you sir. i was obsessed with the number1 at the error a simple if statement solved my problem if(company == null){
                return;
               }